# Object inside json response

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Whenever I select all my items from db, it is being returned as an array of objects. However I want the object to contain another object with data, instead of displaying everything in one JSON. Is this doable somehow?

Below is example which will return

```json
[
  {
   "id": "",
   "name": "",
   "surname": "",
   "date_started": "",
   "school_name": "",
   "graduated": false,
]
```

What I want:

```json
[
  {
   "id": "",
   "name": "",
   "surname": "",
   "date_started": "",
   "school": {
       "school_name": "",
       "graduated": false,
    }
]
```

```java
    public List<Person> getPeople() {
        String sql = "my query";
        List<Person> people = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (result, index) -> {
            return new People(
                    result.getObject("id", java.util.UUID.class),
                    result.getString("name"),
                    result.getString("surname"),
                    result.getDate("date_started"),
                    result.getString("school_name"),
                    result.getBoolean("graduated")
            );
        });
        return people;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is posible:

first create 2 class (bean / dto) such as:

```
public class peopleBean {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String date_started;
    private List<schoolBean> school;
    ...
    
    }
    
public class schoolBean {
    private String school_name;
    private String graduated;
    ...
    
    }
```

then in the getPeople corret it to use listpeople, people_local and school:

```
    public List<Person> getPeople() {
        String sql = "my query";
        List<peobleBean> listpeople = new ArrayList<peopleBean>();
        List<Person> people = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (result, index) -> {
            peopleBean people_local = new peopleBean();
            schoolBean school = new schoolBean();
            return new People(
                    result.getObject("id", java.util.UUID.class),
                    result.getString("name"),
                    result.getString("surname"),
                    result.getDate("date_started"),
                    result.getString("school_name"),
                    result.getBoolean("graduated")
            );
        });
        return listpeople;
    }
```